# Error creating a custom variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using angular2, in the `ngFor` (see below), I can assign value to an attribute, in this case `id`.  The code below works:

```
<div *ngFor="#t in test" id="{{t.num}}">{{t.comment}}</div>
```

However, if I create a custom attribute, I can't do it, I get an error.

```
Can't bind to 'data-value' since it isn't a known native property
```

I tried a lot of different ways but can't do it, I can always assigned to a native attribute (e.g., id, class).

Other things, I have tried:

```
<div *ngFor="#t in test" customAttr="{{t.num}}">{{t.comment}}</div>
<div *ngFor="#t in test" [customAttr]="{{t.num}}">t.comment</div>
<div *ngFor="#t in test" [customAttr]="t.num">t.comment</div>
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using attribute binding syntax:

```
<div *ngFor="#t in test" [attr.data-value]="{{t.num}}">{{t.comment}}</div>
```

Check the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) for details: